# Why does the progressBar keep run when I publish a project to GitHub in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, github

I use GitHub in Visual Studio 2019, I hope to publish a project to GitHub. You can see *Image 1*.

1:  I find the Progress Bar keep run after I click the *Publish to GitHub* button.  You can see *Image 2*, Why?

2: How can I know whether a project has been published to GitHub successfully?

3: Sometimes, I need to click Sync button in order to publish the project to GitHub, why ?

4: What are different between Sync function and Push function in *Image 2* ?

5: Will 'Publish a project to Github ' be run in blackground even if I close Visual Studio? I'm very surprised that 'Repository created successfully' is displayed quickly even if I publish a little big size project to Github. You can see *Image 3*.

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

**Image 3**

[image]

**Added Content:**

To VonC. Thanks!

But the information "Push running in background" displayed, it seems that Push operation run in background, you can see Image 4.

**Image 4**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in "[Share code with push](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pushing?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio)", a sync will push *and* pull.

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/_img/gitquickstart-vs2017/push-to-origin.png?view=azure-devops]

[`problem/187028`](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/187028/git-sync-blocks-ui.html) mentions:

> The reason the UI is blocked when you do a "Sync" (which is a `push` and a `pull`) is that files may be changed on disk. Allowing you to change files while a pull is in progress may lead to lost changes and could lead to unexpected results.

So if you do a Sync, and then are able to work/modify any file, you are sure that everything was pushed/pulled.

The progress bar issue is supposed to be fixed in recent version of Visual Studio, but [problem/159277](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/159277/push-to-visual-studio-team-services-stuck-on-2nd-s.html) included the workaround:

> open the identity picker and select "Add an account".
>   You will then be prompted to choose an identity, and you can choose the one that is currently selected.
>   **The pane should then refresh to show the VSTS account and repo fields**.

---

> It seems that Push operation run in backgound –

Yes: it means you can continue using Visual Studio while the push is processing.
But should you *close* Visual Studio, then the `git push` command would be interrupted, and not complete.

Comment: Thanks! How can I know whether a project has been published to GitHub successfully?

Comment: Do you mean that  'the Progress Bar keep run' is bugs even if I use the   latest Vs 2019 16.4.2 ?

Comment: Will 'Publish a project to Github ' be run in blackground even if I close Visual Studio? I'm very surprised that 'Repository created successfully' is displayed quickly even if I publish a little big size project to Github. You can see Image 3.

Comment: I don't think the push will proceed in background: it would be cancelled if visual studio is closed too soon.

Comment: Thanks! Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?  It seems that Push operation run in backgound

Comment: @HelloCW I have edited my answer to address the background part.